# reference javascript at the beginning or dynamically?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have a small web application I've been working on and the amount of Javascript is starting to build up.  I was wondering what the best practise was ( if there is one) as to when to load/reference your javascript. All at once at the beginning OR as its needed dynamically?

I know how to add the Javascript references dynamically through ajax when parts of my site are loaded and require it?

I hope this question makes sense, I'm still new to this.

Many thanks.

Comment: Well.....depends on the situation. Meaning what is the goal, what do you really want to do and why you need use Javascript or Ajax. You need to know first why we use client side scripting language like JS or Ajax

Comment: If you know how it works, you also should know about the advantages/drawbacks of such a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the size of your JavaScript. It is better to load one `50kb` file at once than having the browser request `50 x 1kb`. First of all I'd recommend minimizing the JavaScript sources and see where that goes.

A great tool for benchmarking your site is [YSlow](http://yslow.org/) which also suggest some improvements you could make. Please do not try to solve everything YSlow criticises as some of the recommendations only make sense for really big sites. (e.g. you are probably not going to need a distributed CDN, etc.)

For JavaScript minification I have very good experience with the [Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) from Google.